# Creating stored procedure not showing up in DB/Null exception

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, smo

I am using SMO to create a temp stored procedure that I would then like to call. So I am doing the following:

```
SMO.StoredProcedure insertSp = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.StoredProcedure(db, "#sp_generate_data");
insertSp.TextMode = false;
insertSp.AnsiNullsStatus = false;
insertSp.QuotedIdentifierStatus = false;
// adding paramaters here
insertSp.TextBody = Sp_Body;                           
insertSp.Create();
```

This code executes fine although when I get around to calling the SP later, it is not found nor is it visible in the DB. I then read that SMO operates in memory until you call alter, and commit the changes so i tried:

```
insertSp.QuotedIdentifierStatus = true;
insertSp.Alter();
```

After the create, to modify a property and alter the SP, however this throws a null exception and I am not sure what is null. What is the correct way of creating a SP through SMO?

Comment: The debugger should tell you what is null or at least narrow it down to a line for you. Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Alter throws it, and the debugger does not seem to point out anything